# Excel - Refer to column/range with Networkdays

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

```
=COUNTIFS(NETWORKDAYS(C:C, TODAY(), 1),">=" & 5)
```

I am trying to use something like the above to count any values in Column C (Date column of my dataset) where the working days from then to todays date is greater than 5. Can this be done without creating a working days column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not so obvious but `NETWORKDAYS` does ***not*** work with ranges. Arrays however are completely fine. See [this](https://superuser.com/q/609193/1059206) post on SuperUser too.

So in your case you could simply use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NETWORKDAYS(C:C+0,TODAY())>=5))
```

Obviously it's better not to reference the whole of column C. Depending if one has Excel O365, you could also just use `=SUM` instead of `=SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: Could I give you more details on what I need? I can see that this is the right approach but I have no experience using array formulas in excel (This is the first I've heard of them) so I can't get it to work for me

Comment: =COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!O:O,">="& 5,'Raw Data'!M:M,"",'Raw Data'!B:B,"EUR")-COUNTIFS('Raw Data'!O:O,">="&10,'Raw Data'!L:L,"Returned",'Raw Data'!B:B,"EUR")

This is my current formula, column O is my workdays column, but this has to be updated as the dataset grows.

My goal is to get rid of column O and reference only column C which is my date column

Comment: I'm not following. Your own formula in the OP uses a `COUNTIFS`, focusses on column C and involves `NETWORKDAYS`, yet in the above comment you mentioned something completely different. If you have more criteria you could build out your `SUMPRODUCT` formula with multiple criteria, e.g.: `=SUMPRODUCT((criteria1)*(criteria2)*(criteria3))`

Comment: If the dataset grows, to avoid using the entire column as C:C or similar, try using a Named Table so that you can refer to the table columns by name. For example, if your table were named Table1, then `=COUNTIFS(Table1[workingdays],">=5",Table1[ColumnM],"",Table1[ColumnB],"EUR")-COUNTIFS(Table1[workingdays],">=10",Table1[ColumnL],"Returned",Table1[ColumnB],"EUR")`. Use Ctrl+T on your range to convert it to a Named table. Edit the table name on the Table Design tab.

Comment: So I currently have a formula calculating the figure I need but it requires adding a column to my dataset; the Workdays column which is column O. The formula I am currently using is the one I commented above. I am trying to avoid having to add this column and in order to do so I attempted the formula in my original question which I used to clarify what I was looking for. sorry for the confusion, does this clear things up?

Comment: @ConorCasey, sort of, currently I think you may need `=SUMPRODUCT((NETWORKDAYS(C:C+0,TODAY())>=5)*(M:M="")*(B:B="EUR"))`. With that you should be able to figure out how to subtract the rest of your formula =). If that didn't help it might be worthwhile to post a new question. **Note**, @FlexYourData has a valid point about using an actual table.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much that's saved me a lot of grief. Will look into array formulas too as this is a new concept for me so thanks for introducing me to the topic

Comment: Last question if you feel like helping, say I wanted to sum a column where those same criteria were met how wold that work? The column I want to sum is column F

Comment: @ConorCasey I'm not sure what you mean. I think at this point you'd better of opening another question.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks again. Answer was to put in column F as the second array in the SUMARRAY for anyone interested